# Australian citizens' internship in France

Tags: visas, australian-citizens, study, schengen-visas

As an Australian, do I need a Schengen visa for doing four months internship in France?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stay more than 90 days you need a national visa (or residence permit but that is normally for longer stays) from France. I don't know what the procedure is for getting such a Visa for an internship in France but I would expect your employer to advise on that.